# Error in deployment of jruby on rails project to jboss

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jboss, jruby

I am getting an Internal Server Error (500) when deploying jruby on rails on jboss. I have created a war file copy it into the /standalone/deployments folder. It was deployed successfully but when I ran it on myip:8080/untitled3/ it throws an error.

Following is the message:

```
       exit from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:877:in `exit' from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:840:in `exit' from /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempc74de2204c8bbfcb/untitled3.war-a2aee82210e177c/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.0/lib/bundler/setup.rb:14:in `(root)' from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require' from classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1:in `(root)' from classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require' from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require' from /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempc74de2204c8bbfcb/untitled3.war-a2aee82210e177c/WEB-INF/config/boot.rb:4:in `(root)' from classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1:in `(root)' from classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' from classpath:/jruby/rack/rails/environment3.rb:23:in `load_environment'
```

Does anyone have idea as to why i am getting this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as the trace suggests ... the Rails boot `Bundler.require` line is failing and than exit-ing.
that is likely caused by some gems not being bundled right in the .war (try to reproduce with an empty app and the same *Gemfile* ... if there's no local gem :path references it would be worth reporting)

Comment: kares it is an empty project the gems installed are all that comes out of the box. I am looking at the log file and it contains the following:

       11:38:41,258 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/untitled3]] (http--192.168.20.191-8080-1) DEBUG: due a previous initialization failure application instance can not be returned
11:38:41,259 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/untitled3]] (http--192.168.20.191-8080-1) DEBUG: resetting rack response due exception

Well i'll give it a shot by removing few gems

Comment: those are not really useful - just pointing to a "previous initialization failure" ... which is the thing we're after. in case it's just a simple empty app maybe you can show the pieces e.g. in a github repo.

Comment: kares turns out you were correct there was one gem installed which was causing the problem. It is now working fine.